# Accessing data in an array

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at this and reading for a while but can't seem to understand.  I am sure it is simple but I can not figure out why I can access the data in collection.  I get an error of

> test undefined

If I move outside of the for loop I can access it just fine.  I am obviously missing something simple. Any help would be great.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  // Only change ode below this line
  var test = Object.values(source);

  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i].test === source[0].test){
      arr[i] = collection[i];
    }
  }

  // Only change code above this line
  //arr = collection[0].last;
  return arr; 
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", 
last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Comment: `collection[i].test` where does the object you are passing to the function have `test` ? Both `source` and `collection`

Comment: FreeCodeCamp i guss?!

Comment: No element of `collection` or `source` appears to have a property named `test`.

Comment: `test` is a variable, not a property. `source` is an object, not an array, so `source[0]` is undefined. Read the error carefully. It says something like “Cannot access property `test` of undefined”. Which means that `source[0]` is undefined, not `test`.

Comment: Thanks I see that in the error code now.  The trick was to use brackets. source[test] works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code Object.values returning the value of source that is "Capulet", whereas in for loop you are equating source as an array(source is object), that is why, test is undefined

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  // Only change ode below this line
  
  
  var test = Object.keys(source);//changes values to keys
  console.log(test);
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i][test] === source[test]){ //change how you are accessing test
      arr.push(collection[i]);
    }
  }

  // Only change code above this line
  //arr = collection[0].last;
  console.log(arr);
  return arr; 
}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", 
last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects you're passing in have no key named `test`. If you're trying to use the variable you created here `var test = Object.values(source);`, this won't work because `test` is an array anyways.

You could try something like:

```
if (collection[i][test] === source[0][test])
```

but I don't think that will work either because `test` should have the value of `Capulet` according to documentation for `Object.values()`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(source);

  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var item = collection[i];
      var all = true;
      for(var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++){
          var key = keys[k];
          if(item[key] != source[key]){
            all = false;
            break;
          }
      }
      if(all){
          arr.push(item)
      }
  }

  return arr; 
}
```